# Issue with string in c#?

Tags: c#

I am creating a string in c#.

```
string jsVersion = @"function getContent() {
                     var content = " + "\"" + documentString + "\"" + @"
                     return content; 
                     }";
```

The documentString variable contains a huge string which have line breaks also. Now in javascript when i load this string the content variable does not contains a valid string (because of line breaks).

Now how can i create a string which is valid even if there is line breaks ?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `jsVersion`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use string.format instead of concatenation in this fashion?

An example:

```
string jsVersion = string.format("function getContent() {var content = '{0}'return content; }",documentString);
```

Comment: You still need to do extra JavaScript escaping, I think.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914.aspx)

Comment: a detailed answer would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

This will replace your line breaks with `<br/>`:-

```
stringToDecode.replace(/\n/, '&lt;br /&gt;')
```

Comment: I think what it needs is `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the line breaks just remove `@` from the sting.

`@` acts a verbatim for your string and therefor adds the line breaks you entered with your declaration.

```
string jsVersion = "function getContent() {
                     var content = " + "\"" + documentString + "\"" + "
                     return content; 
                     }";
```

should do the trick.